# Clean up after install Lubuntu, was Ubuntu before

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, configuration

I use an old PC with 8 Go RAM, but it become slower, so I installed Lubuntu to boost it a little. But the old config with normal Ubuntu stays, and slowed my config when it starts.
How to clean my configs (without reinstalling a new fressh install of Lubuntu), to keep only Lubuntu on my PC.
Thank you for your help
Jacques

Comment: How did you "install Lubuntu" over an existing Ubuntu install? Did you just install `lubuntu-desktop` or what?  Edit your answer to provide details and someone may be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. On a normal Ubuntu install, I add lubuntu-desktop, and I after that, I choose Lubuntu. But I don't know how to clean my desktop, without installing a fresh distro